# Query MongoDB with Custom URL filters

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, express

Creating an API for various different displays. Would like to retrieve all the displays in the database and then pass custom query strings to then filter down further. Been researching all day on how to do this and nothing has made complete sense or wasn't able to get it to work completely as expected.

A Sample URL: `localhost:3000/api/v1/displays?hdmi=true&hdmi_version=1.2`. In theory these custom queries could range from all different specifications displays have that include different values (strings, booleans, and integers).

**Technologies**

- Express: 4.13.4
- Node: 5.6.0
- MongoDB (local): 3.2.4
- Angular: 1.5, will be eventual front end but just trying to build the API and use POSTman

**Database:**

```
[
  {
    "_id": "572be4122847a355994a07d9",
    "series": "meh-monitor",
    "hdmi": false,
    "hdmi_version": "",
    "vga": true,
    "resolution": "1366x768"
  },
  {
    "_id": "572be4122847a355994a07da",
    "series": "ok-monitor",
    "hdmi": true,
    "hdmi_version": "1.0",
    "vga": true,
    "resolution": "1920x1080"
  },
  {
    "_id": "572be4122847a355994a07db",
    "series": "good-monitor",
    "hdmi": true,
    "hdmi_version": "1.2",
    "vga": false,
    "resolution": "2560x1440"
  }
]
```

**Express - `server.js`**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var db = mongojs('products', ['displays']);
var apiVersion = "v1";
```

So I can get all the displays with:

```
app.get('/'+apiVersion+'/displays', function(req, res){
  db.displays.find(function(err,docs){
    if(err){
      res.send(err);
    }
    else{
      return res.json(docs);
    }
  });
});
```

OR get specific displays with id parameter:

```
// GET ONE ENTRY
app.get('/'+apiVersion+'/displays/:id', function(req,res){
  db.displays.findOne({_id:mongojs.ObjectID(req.params.id)},function(err,doc){
    if(err){
      res.send(err);
    }
    else{
      return res.json(doc);
    }
  });
});
```

The issue is just passing custom parameters. Tried to use [mongo-querystring](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-querystring) which kind of worked but, was unable to filter by `hdmi_version=#.#` or `resolution=####x####`. Also the documentation examples weren't completely clear to me.

Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get parameters via req.query.paramName. Query the db as shown.

So, for something like: `localhost:3000/api/v1/displays?hdmi=true&hdmi_version=1.2&resolution=1920x1080`

Since the URL parameters, may or may not exist, you also have to check first.

```
app.get('/'+apiVersion+'/displays', function(req,res){

  //To print the parameters
  console.log(req.query.hdmi);
  console.log(req.query.resolution);

  //Remember to sanitize the query before passing it to db
  var query = {};
  if (req.query.resolution) query.resolution = req.query.resolution;
  if (req.query.resolution) query.hdmi = req.query.hdmi;

  db.displays.find(query, function(err, displays){
    if (err) {
      res.send(err);
    }
    else {
      return res.json(displays);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for getting me pointed in the right direction this is extremely helpful. Noticed that this doesn't parse booleans correctly. for `http//...?hdmi=true` it's looking to find the string value `{hdmi: 'true'}`, is that an accurate assumption?

Comment: yes, since it has no way of differentiating any data type from the url param.
`var myBool = Boolean(param);`  to convert

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, makes sense. Thanks again for the answer.